# How to set three level of tab in Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

How to set three levels of tab in Idea like at this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't set the number of rows of tabs that are displayed, but you can switch from one row to multiple rows.

1. Select **File** > **Settings** from the menu.
2. Navigate to **Editor** > **General** > **Editor Tabs**.
3. Disable the **Show tabs in one row** checkbox.

[image: IntelliJ]

The **Tab limit** setting allows you to specify the maximum number of open tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Window -> Editor Tabs -> Configure Editor Tabs...`

Uncheck *Show Tabs in one row*.

This will give you two rows by default. The reason is the **Tab limit**, which is set to **10** by default. Setting this value to, for example 100, will add more rows as long as you have 100 or less tabs opened.